# XTemplate and style

Tags: extjs

I have an XTemplate for tooltips

```
tooltipTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
'<dl class="eventTip">',
'<table width="100%"><tr>',
'<td width="10%">',
'<table><tr>',
'<td><dt class="entry_{EventType}"></dt></td>',
...
```

which renders completely and all data is shown and the class is applied correctly.

Then I added a new field to all records in the store at runtime:

```
eventRec.set('evtColor',"#EFEFEF");
```

and added the new field to the template:

```
tooltipTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
'<tpl exec="console.log(values.evtColor);"></tpl>',
'<dl class="eventTip" style="background-color:{values.evtColor};">',
```

The result is that #EFEFEF is logged to console, but the tooltip is rendered neither completely nor with #EFEFEF as background-color.

Why is that? How do I get the background color into the tooltip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to prepend `values.` when using curly brackets, just use `{evtColor}` and it should work.